# powershell script to search and copy files linked on https site

Tags: powershell, https, httpwebrequest

How do i modify my script to search for files on https?

```
$source = "https://mysite/searchfolder"
$destination = "\\Transfer"

$searchFiles = Import-CSV 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test2.csv' -Header ("filename")

ForEach($File in $searchFiles) 
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $File.filename } | Copy-Item -Destination $destination    
}
```

This script gives the error

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'https' does not exist.
```

I've been reading that I'll probably need to use `Invoke-WebRequest` but I'm not sure how to build that into my script. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: If you hover over the httpwebrequest tag you'll see "HttpWebRequest is a class for .NET Framework applications". You shouldn't use that tag for questions not related to the .NET framework class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't search files on https if your server doesn't expose a service to list directories. You won't find a cmdlet for that nor will you be able to do that with other programming languages.

Comment: OK. does intranet make a difference? If I see all the files are located in https://intranet.me.org/ScanningRep0505, for example https://intranet.me.org/ScanningRep0505/A001.pdf...i still can't access them via powershell?

Comment: Not via http if the webserver doesn't expose such service.

Comment: I would assume that those files are hosted locally on your intranet server then or at least somewhere you can access a share hidden or otherwise. You could in theory search that directory instead of trying to go via http

Comment: @val You can always combine $source and $File to a new request url though, and simply attempt to fetch each file from the server. Though if it complains about the "https" part I'm not sure if you even can make such requests from powershell.